# Conditional probability question 4

Tags: probability

I'm studying for my finals and I'm stuck at this question. I know the solution for a) is 10/13 and b) is 2/3, I just wasn't able to get there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Here it is:**

In a secondary school there are two classes of multimedia professional course (classes A and B).

For these two classes, it is known that:

- 64% of the students are boys;
- a third of the girls are in class A;
- class B has as many boys and girls.

Choosing a student at random.

- **a)** What is the probability the student is a boy knowing that it is in class A?
- **b)** What is the probability the student is in class B knowing that it is a girl?

**EDIT**

I managed to get to the solution with the hint from @drhab: https://goo.gl/photos/35NuE1EHjtgBMJmL7

But, I'm pretty sure this is not a valid solution for the real exam since I can't "assume" any values. I need to get there by the formulas or with a tree.

**EDIT**

OK, I think I got it, I can just use the probabilities given (which is basically just dividing everything by 100).

Comment: Can you show us first what you have tried and exactly where you get stuck?  We're not supposed to just answer questions cold because some people may be using us to just do their HW for them.  So when posting questions like this please add some of your thoughts on the solution.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Please check my edit.

Comment: that's better. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**:

Let it be that there are exactly $100$ students.

Now find how the classes are updivided in boys and girls.

Now find the probabilities.

Now wonder if there will be essential changes if there are e.g. $1000$ students.

Comment: Thank you. Please check my edit.

Comment: That looks good. You can make it complete by addin % to the numbers in the table.

Comment: Also you can say $24x$ etc. instead of $24$ where $x$ is an unknown positive number. It falls away when you calculate the probabilities because $\frac{x}{x}=1$. So you are not bothered by it.

Answer (score 0):

$p(\text{boy}|A)=\frac {p(\text{boy}\cap A)}{p(A)}=\frac {0.4}{0.52}=\frac{10}{13}$

$p(B|\text{girl})=\frac {p(B\cap \text{girl})}{p(\text{girl})}=\frac {0.24}{0.36}=\frac{2}{3}$

Comment: How did you calculate p(boy∩A) and p(B∩girl)? Thanks.

Comment: By drawing up a contingency table, but I don't know how to set this up in MathJax